# What defines a physical property?

Tags: soft-question, definition, dimensional-analysis

The physical world around us has all sorts of properties, shape, color etc. If you move on to more complex systems, there are even more like some emotional properties etc.

Why do we deem only certain of them as physical like mass, length, time etc. and not others?

Comment: Because you can say $\text{mass}=3\ \mathrm{kg}$, but $\text{love}=1.1\ \mathrm{hearts}$ is meaningless...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Sure, I can establish a scale for love by taking an ex's love equal to say 1.1 hearts and a mother's love as 1000000 hearts and put everyone else in between this spectrum

Comment: In physics, we prefer to deal with quantities you can directly measure with simple tools, because they're easier to handle. You can make up any property you want, but what can you do with it? Can you find equations of motion for "love"?

Comment: According to your spectrum, what would be my love for your question? Can you give a number for it?

Comment: You can't devise a numeric scale until you have a loveometer. Seriously: the numbers have to mean something objectively reproducible.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Sure, I can ask you and based on my previous available data that I gather, I can put your love at the correct place on the scale. Just like you do with mass or length,

Comment: A physical property is defined by the experimental procedure that reduces it to fundamental physical constants and normals. How do you want to reduce love to $\hbar$ and a kilogram prototype?

Comment: @CuriousOne Who decides these fundamental physical quantities?

Comment: many physical properties are emergent in the domains of weather, Fluid mechanics , etc

Comment: [My normal approach is useless, here.](https://xkcd.com/55/)

Comment: Who decides the fundamental quantities? Nature. We merely observe.

Comment: @CuriousOne You people are seriously driving this website to doom. Please stop using it or give up your moderation priveleges. I see a lot of questions here in the past, which if you'd have been around wouldn't have gathered amazin answers from some people where were really good at physics like Ron and others. You people aren't allowing good general questions to be asked here, and don't like being questioned at your understanding of basics. Basically all of you people, have gone through certain courses at university and learnt to calculate and built your intuition based on solving problems.

Comment: @CuriousOne And now you don't want a question that is kind of fundamental to be asked, to gather answers from people who are brilliant and who haven't let their independent thoughts die in classroom, like all of you have

Comment: That includes you too @JohnRennie who believes in many worlds interpretation. Lol.

Comment: @Qmechanic I feel sorry for this website, which was once a great place and is now being ruined by people like these. If I was the mod, I'd make sure to kick these people out, who vote to close a question without giving a reasonable justification, and can't tolerate a question that isn't immediately related to something that you only ask during a physics lecture

Comment: You all have been too institutionalized and have ruined physics stackexchange. Seriously, I wish it could be saved, it was a wonderful place, but till the time you people are present here. It won't ever be.

Comment: The website is dominated by people lacking original thought and having no experience at guessing new laws of nature, and who are only good physics students, who'll probably scoring great on tests and would be able to answer many of the question in the similar category, that are asked during learning "how to do" a particular sub field of physics.

Comment: @Meme: You asked a question and I gave the correct answer. Nature decides what good fundamental quantities are. This is physics and not philosophy. It's about describing observations, not about coming up with what the "inevitable" future course of history will be (look how well that worked out). If you don't like to be here because of the responses that you are getting, there is a simple solution: don't be here. Be somewhere else where they like you more. Fair?

Comment: Sure, I am not going to be here, but there are certain things that are right. You have a lot of people backing you here, I guess because of similar thought process that you have gained, but that doesn't mean you stand correct. Yes, your answer was correct, but was too succinct and wasn't actually an answer at all if you ask me, since it merely stated the obvious without explaining anything. It infact could be the answer to anything in physics, but a certain amount of explanation needs to be given when someone is learning. @KyleKanos

Comment: but you shouldn't have voted to close the question then. Anyways, I have seen your ways in the past, and more than you I am disappointed with other people here like Kyle who spends his time moderating here, LOL. I do not own this site and I am not going to gain any benefit off of it when people like these dominate it. @CuriousOne

Comment: Physics is a tool, just like a wrench. Just like a wrench it fits on certain nuts and it doesn't fit on others. It's really that simple. You can't apply it to everything in life. Not sure why you are so emotional about that fact. Yes, physics is also about stating the obvious. What is obvious to a physicist depends on how much they have learned about nature. I can assure you that a lot of things are "obvious" to Edward Witten that I will never, ever even begin to understand. I can live with that. As for your personal "disappointments"... I don't think anybody here cares.

Answer (score 4):

This is, as you stated in the title of the question, a problem of definition.

In order to be useful for Physics (and most Science), there is a key characteristic of the properties we use: they have to be **objectively measurable**. As dmckee stated in a comment to the question, the property does not only need to be able to be put in scale (as you said, you could make a scale of love), that alone is not useful for Physics. You have to be able to make a objective scale reproducible by anyone (for example, you could measure the activity in the brain area responsible of affection, but not love itself, as it differ with the person). That does not mean that you can't do Science with other properties, it just mean that they are not useful with methodology in Physics.

This is why some scales as the [dol scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unusual_units_of_measurement#Pain) for pain don't measure physical properties, it depends on the person. They might be useful in other areas.

Comment: I think, a better answer could be that one starts studying a part of the real world, such as mechanics and decides the basic properties that one would  require in the beginning and as you go on you see if they were sufficient and add more if need be. Then you study another part of the physical world, like say thermodynamics or electromagnetism. And come up with more quantities that may be required

Comment: Then as you mature, you get to make connections between different branches and learn to say some measurable quantities in terms of others, like say temperature in terms of kinetic energy

Comment: So, in short it'd be more like trial and error.